# Showing form throws System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  izvjesti_pokusaj_2.Izvjestaji dajboze = new izvjesti_pokusaj_2.Izvjestaji();
  dajboze.Show();
}

public partial class Izvjestaji : Form
{
    public Izvjestaji()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Close();
    }

    public void Button_izvjestaj(object sender, EventArgs e) { 

        var Pomocni = (Button)sender;


        switch (Pomocni.Name) {
            case "Izvjestaji_radnici":  
                  Radnici_izvjestaj Izvještaj = new Radnici_izvjestaj();
            Izvještaj.Show();

                break;        
        }

    }
}
```

Can somebody explain why when it try to show dajboze he throw a exception "System.ObjectDisposedException"  Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object. ?

Comment: Please post code in `dajboze.show()`

Comment: wt... can you show what does this do izvjesti_pokusaj_2.Izvjestaji()?

Comment: Get rid of that `this.Close()` after the `InitializeComponent();`  Why would you have that line there?

Comment: i want to kill the last form

Comment: if i put this.close() in the ublic void Button_izvjestaj(object sender, EventArgs e) it close all forms

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. You want 1 form to popup and close the *other* form that opened it? You'll need a reference to that opening form in the new form's constructor, then close *that*. Right now you're creating a form, which closes itself in its own constructor, then you try to call `Show` on it after it's already been closed (read: disposed of)

Comment: in no case will `this` refer to some other form.

Comment: yes..but how can i reference to it..when the form that i want to close is the main form.. she dont have a reference or?

Comment: #Plutonix yes..i had a reference from another form there..and i forget to delete that  " this.close()"